# CSS Media queries not working as required

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have two divs that are 368px x 228px sitting next to each other but each time I try to apply media queries and run a few tests, it doesn't seem to be working at all. How do I go about resolving this issues.

See my code below:

```
<style type="text/css">

  .block-content-right {
    background-color:#e0e620;
    flex:1;
   }

   @media (max-width: 600px) {
    .field__item {
    width: 100%; 
      }
    }

    @media (min-width: 400px) {
     .field__item {
     width: 100%; 
       }
    }

 </style>

<div class="block-content-right">
<p>The people the people the people</p> 
</div>

<div class="field__item">
<img src="blah blah.jg";> 
</div>
```

[image]

Need some help guys. Thank you.

Comment: Do you also have this `<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />`?

Comment: What is not working in particular? Both of your media queries are specifying `.field__item{ width: 100%; }`. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: You are using 100% in both cases. I have changed this and the media queries are working. Check out the changing backgrounds I have added in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/xbea736y/. Your sample code does not reflect what you describe, e.g. img width, etc. Maybe you can add code with sample images and explain in detail what you expect.

Comment: If someone answered your question you mark one as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your media queries are working, but at least one of them is always going to be active.

Perhaps what you wanted was this:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) and (min-width: 400px) {
  /* This will be active if the screen is between 600px and 400px */
.field__item {
width: 100%; 
  }
}
```

Or maybe this:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) or (min-width: 600px) {
  /* This will be active if the screen is NOT between 600px and 400px */
.field__item {
width: 100%; 
  }
}
```

**Note:** For testing purposes, you may want to use a different CSS rule. With the code you are showing, the "width: 100%;" doesn't do anything because divs have 100% width by default. Try using "border:5px solid red;"

**Code to stack elements if the page is narrow:** (Going into full screen causes the elements to be placed side-by-side)

```css
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .half-width {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="half-width" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d7/Zinnia_elegans_with_Bombus_01.JPG/640px-Zinnia_elegans_with_Bombus_01.JPG" />
<div class="half-width">Here is some text. More and more and more text. And more and more text. And more and more text. And more and more text. And more and more text. And more and more text. And more and more text.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. What I would like is for the 2 divs to be stacked on top of each other at different view ports i.e mobile and tablet views. The result I currently get is one div overlapping over the other, which is not ideal.

Comment: I updated the answer to include an example of stacking elements.